# Prevent NodeJS npm from printing details when retrieving package

Tags: node.js, npm

Using the node npm module (https://www.npmjs.org/api/npm.html), I want to retrieve a package but NOT have it print the results to console.  Setting loglevel silent does not seem to help.

```
var npm = require('npm');
npm.load(function (er, npm) {
  // use the npm object, now that it's loaded.

  npm.config.set('loglevel', 'silent');

  npm.commands.view(["<package>@<version>"],function(err, npmBody) {
    //at this point it is always logging npmBody contents to console!
  });

});
```

Comment: Did you try passing in an initial config setting e.g. `npm.load({loglevel: 'silent'}, function (er, npm){...});` and/or trapping the log event `npm.on("log", function (message) { ... })`? I have to run out or would test it myself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can't be done without hijacking `stdout`. See: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/lib/install.js#L100

This was fixed once, but then reverted. It appears that `npm` is not designed to be use programmatically.

By "hijacking `stdout`" I mean something like this:

```
console.log('Begin');

console._stdout = { write : function () {} };

externalFn();

console._stdout = process.stdout;

console.log('End');



function externalFn () {
    console.log('Annoying stuff');
}
```